# Get value from SharedPreferences without future builder

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I need to get one stored value from shared preferences and put it into text widget. How can I do this without a future builder?

```
_currPage() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int page = prefs.getInt('currPage') ?? 0;
  return page;
}
```

```
class _AllTasksPageState extends State<AllTasksPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  Text(_currPage()); //not working
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  int page = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('$page'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void readData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getInt('currPage') == null)
      setState(() => page = 0);
    else
      setState(() => page = prefs.getInt('currPage')!);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

create a helper class just for shared preferences

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SPHelper {
  SPHelper._();
  static SPHelper sp = SPHelper._();
  SharedPreferences? prefs;
  Future<void> initSharedPreferences() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  Future<void> save(String name, String value) async {
    await prefs!.setString(name, value);
  }

  String? get(String key) {
    return prefs!.getString(key);
  }

  Future<bool> delete(String key) async {
    return await prefs!.remove(key);
  }
}
```

in your main function add

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SPHelper.sp.initSharedPreferences();
  ...
  runApp(MyApp());
  ...
}
```

then to get your data just write
`SPHelper.sp.get("YOUR_KEY")`

and to store your data just write
`SPHelper.sp.save("YOUR_KEY","YOUR_VALUE")`

This is the best way to use shared preference.

I hope that's will help you in your problem.

Comment: This is not the best way to use shared preferences, and creating more boiler plate code. Future builder is the simples and cleanest method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is using a SharedPreferences provider:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider.value(value: await SharedPreferences.getInstance()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: AllTasksPage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class AllTasksPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AllTasksPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final page = context.read<SharedPreferences>().getInt('currPage') ?? 0;
    return Scaffold(body: Text('$page'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use a future builder, the other solution is if you have a variable that tells you that are you still waiting/loading data and if yes, show a waiting screen:

```
class _AllTasksPageState extends State<AllTasksPage> {
bool _loading = true;
String? textValue; // String textValue = "";

@override
initState() {
   super.initState();
   setTextValue();
}

setTextValue() {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int page = prefs.getInt('currPage') ?? 0;
  setState(() {
     textValue = "$page";
     _loading = false;
  });
}


// then in the build method
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return _loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : actualScreen();
 }
}
```